# Using a user defined variable within a function? (Ruby, Watir)

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm creating drag and drop feature that depends on upon ID for placement, it works perfectly fine, but I need the status of task to be user defined so the user will have control of where something will be dragged as each section is uniquely named.

getID refers to getting the reference id of a Div.

I'd then concatenating with a "_" as well as adding the user set word

Class:

```
def addtask
    dropTask = @browser.div(:id => getID+"_"+"@#{statusOfTask}")
    dragTask = @browser.div(:id, "footer").span(:class, "headerDrag")
    dragTask.drag_and_drop_on dropTask 
end
```

User Script:

```
statusOfTask = ["Ready"]
addtask()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass the desired status text to the addTask() method.

Class (add statusOfTask as a parameter):

```
def addtask(statusOfTask)
    dropTask = @browser.div(:id => getID+"_"+"@#{statusOfTask}")
    dragTask = @browser.div(:id, "footer").span(:class, "headerDrag")
    dragTask.drag_and_drop_on dropTask 
end
```

User Script (pass in the first (or desired) value of statusOfTask):

```
statusOfTask = ["Ready"]
addtask(statusOfTask[0])
```

Comment: I get an error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)?

                                                                using: statusOfTask = ["Blocked", "Ready", "InPogress", "AwaitingReview", "Done"]

addtask(statusOfTask[0])

Comment: Did you update the addTask method definition? Notice that the definition should be addtask(statusOfTask).

Comment: Worked fine in the end, turned out it the @ wasn't required, even though from research I thought it was necessary.  Thanks, for the help!